# Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable in Azure Function

Tags: environment-variables, azure-functions, azure-caching

How bad it is to use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` in Azure Functions? Based on my initial observation it seems it is working as expected (ie. storing the value and returning when I asked using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` call) but not showing anywhere in the environment variables list when I open the function in Kudu explorer. Where it is setting, is it okay to use or any adverse effects of using it?

In my case, I have to get the user details using the token passed to Function headers. I don't want to keep retrieving the ID for the user again and again rather I want to cache some where. Thought of using Redis cache but a) I'm using V1 functions due to some libraries issue b)Just for one variable at least for now, I thought it is too costly. any other suggestions?

Thank you
-Srikanth

Comment: This is about the worst possible way to use an environment variable. Why not rather create a singleton-scoped class that holds that token and inject it to set the token once, then inject it wherever you need it?

Comment: thank @IanKemp. I thought it is bad but don't know why :), For the token anyways i'm doing that. but it is another variable that I have to get based on the AD User that authenticated. So, I got the token -> gives me the principal user id -> get the user record from CRM using this user id/email -> store that user record across invocations. Coz' I know this user is going to hit the function multiple times (it may be in 5 mins or more than that).This AD account will always have the same user record in CRM, it doesnt makes sense to me to keep retrieving the same record.

Comment: actually, I'm interested in learning why, where it stores, what complications it would produce etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the variable by `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`, it will not show in application setting. But we can use it by `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` as expected. Although the solution you mentioned is not so good, but it can implement your requirement. The adverse effect is **when you restart the function app, the variables will be lost**.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks for the inputs @Hury Shen . This is what I'm looking for. As long as there are no major issues (loosing them when I restart function app may not be a big concern, possibly for that 1 call, it might take a bit of time to get the details but all the followed 100 calls will save time.